# How to design a SearchHandler in Solr

Tags: solr, solrconfig

I have designed a SearchHandler in Solr, but I don't know why the Rank and Shards does not work. Here is the config for the `requestHandler`:

```
<requestHandler name="/contentsearch" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
  <str name="shards">localhost:8983/solr/Wiki,localhost:8983/solr/iShare,localhost:8983/solr/GRA,localhost:8983/solr/ACF</str>
  <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
  <str name="wt">json</str>
  <str name="indent">true</str>

  <str name="defType">edismax</str>
  <str name="qf">
    title^100.0 content^80.0 text^60.0
  </str>
  <str name="q">*:*</str>
  <str name="indent">true</str>
  <str name="rows">10</str>

  <!-- Facet settings -->
  <str name="facet">on</str>
  <str name="facet.field">content_type</str>
  <str name="facet.field">category</str>
  <str name="facet.field">author</str>
  <str name="facet.field">editor</str>
  <str name="facet.field">source_type</str>

  <str name="hl">on</str>
  <str name="hl.fl">title content</str>
</lst>    
<arr name="last-components">
  <str>elevator</str>
</arr></requestHandler>
```

The 4 core schemas are same. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please also specify the exact Solr version and also add the actual result and the expected outcome you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi @LeftyGBalogh is 6.1.0

Comment: @LeftyGBalogh I want use shard to search 4 core, and i need to highlight title & content field if it mapping the keywords

Comment: Hi @LeftyGBalogh I think I know why the Rank it does not work, But I still no have idea why the shards it'll error, About the error message you can see below,

Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/Wiki: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text

Comment: Is anyone know how to use shards in Solr Searchhandler?